# Gerar Relatorios com grande fluxo de dados (PHP e Mysql )

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando gerar relatórios do banco de dados com um grande fluxo de dados *(entre 10 mil e 150 mil dados)*, colocando este dados em um arquivo *csv* ou *xlsx* (Excel), queria saber se tem um forma otimizada para isso.
Meu pensamento e ter um botão na tela onde o cliente clica e efetua o download deste arquivo no formato especificado.

> Alguém tem alguma dica qual o melhor caminho a seguir?

Comment: Amigão, eu utilizo PHPJasper[link](https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper) pois tu pode construir os modelos e depois utilizados; também tem o complemento do JasperStudio[link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) para auxiliar na construção dos modelos.